# Pseudodifferential operators and amplitudes

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

I am studying psudodifferential operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open subset. A function is $b\in C^\infty(U\times U\times U \times \mathbb{R}^n)$ is an *amplitude* of *order* $r$ if for any multiindices $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, there is constant $C_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
sup_{x,y\in U} |D^\alpha _xD^\beta _yD^\gamma _\xi b(x,y,\xi)|\leq C_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} (1+|\xi|)^{r-|\gamma|}.
\end{equation}
 A *pseudodifferential operator* is given by 
\begin{equation}
B\phi (x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_U e^{i(x-y)\xi}b(x,y,\xi)\phi(y) dy d\xi.
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, I don't understand why if I have an amplitude defining a pseudodifferential operator, and the amplitude vanishes in a neighborhood of the diagonal, then it is of order $-\infty$. I thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because then you can use the identity 
$$
\frac1{i(x-y)^2}(x-y)\frac\partial{\partial \xi}e^{i(x-y)\xi}=e^{i(x-y)\xi} 
$$
to integrate by parts as many times as you wish and obtain an ampitude of arbitrary large negative order $r-N$, where $N$ is the number of integration by parts. Specifically,
$$
 \int e^{i(x-y)\xi}b(x,y,\xi)\phi(y)d\xi dy=\int\left(\left[\frac1{i(x-y)^2}(x-y)\frac\partial{\partial \xi}\right]^N e^{i(x-y)\xi}\right)b(x,y,\xi)\phi(y)d\xi dy\\
=(-1)^N\int e^{i(x-y)\xi}\left(\left[\frac1{i(x-y)^2}(x-y)\frac\partial{\partial \xi}\right]^N b(x,y,\xi)\right)\phi(y)d\xi dy.
$$
The amplitude in parentheses is smooth (because $b\equiv0$ in a neighborhood of the diagonal $x=y$) and is of order $r-N$ if $b$ is an amplitude of order $r$.

Comment: Also, there are many good books on $\psi$DO, why not to use them?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand your answer. In order to say that an amplitude has order $-\infty$ I should prove inequalities like the first one, which doesn't involve integral. I think I am missing something in your answer, could you be more specific. Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited my answer. This computation is one of the first computations seen in any textbook on $\psi$DO. Why do not you use such books? I recommend Shubin or H"ormander.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By the way I am using a textbook, but unfortunately this property was stated without proof. However, thanks for the recommendations about the books.